# Select all except one field in SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, select, pdo

I would like to create a function which select all the characters with their properties in the db except the one who execute this function and because I'm new with SQL, I'm wondering if there was a way to do that : `SELECT * FROM 'table name' EXCEPT 'the character executing the function'`.

For example, if a player in a rpg game wants to attack someone, I would like to put the whole list of other players in the database that he can attacks. But if I do `SELECT * FROM 'table name'`, he will be in the list and I don't want him to attack himself...

I search on Google and here but I only found solution for selecting all except a column, but i want that for a field.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should add an example because it's not clear what you want

Comment: You cannot select all columns but one with a command, the only solution typing all fields you want.

Comment: I have never heard of NOT IN, can someone explain me what is that ?

Comment: BarnardoLima: I'm talking about fields, not column

Comment: I did not get what 'the character executing the function' means.

Comment: Well field in database term mean column

Comment: Add an clear example of what you want to do, and we should be able to help you

Comment: You could make your question more understandable by giving a concrete example instead of an abstract database table. What is the current character? A user perhaps? What DB field should it not match?

Comment: Can someone erase the down vote ? I will not be able to ask questions again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM 'tableName' WHERE characterId != 5
```

5 here being the ID from the character executing the function

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't understand how I didn't think about that Maybe I'm tired ahahah !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `sub query`. Get all names those are already executed the function & keep these name in `NOT IN`. For information keep a records for those name who executed the function. `NOT IN` example

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name NOT IN (
     SELECT name FROM table_name_where_executed_name_stored WHERE executed = 1
)
```

Comment: Is this solution better than Jonathan Cloutier one ?

Comment: That all depend on your need, if you wan't to exclude more than one row use this one, if you only need to exclude one row, the other is simpler to use.